# Query Regarding Mumps Statement

Tags: mumps

what is the meaning of `F :":::A:""T"""::$X::::"*":J%%` this statement?

Answer (score 3):

This statement is not valid syntax.

The `F` or `FOR` command followed by a single space must be in the following form:

```
F[OR]  lvn = forparameter

  forparameter  ::= 
     │ expr1                          |
     │ numexpr1 : numexpr2 : numexpr3 |
     │ numexpr1 : numexpr2            |
```

`lvn` is a local variable name.

In your code, there is no `lvn=` following the for command.

More details in the [annotated MUMPS Standards](http://71.174.62.16/Demo/AnnoStd).

Answer (score 2):

Agreed, this is an invalid Mumps line.  Some context might help if you're still looking for an answer.

Something else to keep in mind is that if there are 2 spaces after the F[OR] statement, then it will infinitely loop.  Usually a line like that will also contain a:

```
Q[UIT]:condition
```

for example:

```
 NEW A
 SET A=""
 F
```

OR `SET A=$ORDER(^GLOBAL(A)) QUIT:A=""  DO SpecialStuff(A)`

Hope that helps!